# Using external css in freemarker when string temlpate loader is used

Tags: css, freemarker

Case 1 : I have used `<#include <cssFilePath>/style.css>`in ftl when template file is loaded from template directiory(`setClassForTemplateLoading` i was using in this case) as file and was able to do all styling work.

Case 2: Now, As my ftl and css files will be moved to db.I am planing to use `StringTemplateLoader` for loading freemarker template as string. But how can i use the css file which will be loaded from db as string in the ftl templates?

Comment: Load the CSS from a separate URL as you would normally do in HTML. So create a servlet or REST endpoint.

Comment: Is there any other way to do without creating servlet or REST ( I dont know about them )

Answer (score 2):

If some templates will come from a `StringTemplateLoader`, and some others (the CSS) from some other `TemplateLoader` (the one that loads from DB), then you can use `MultiTemplateLoader`, which searches templates in multiple `TemplateLoaders`.

Also note that you can create `Template`-s directly from a `String` with the `Template(String name, String sourceCode, Configuration cfg)` constructor. Then `#include` will still use the `TemplateLoader` set in the FreeMarker `Configuration`. Caching the `Template`-s (if you need that for performance reasons) that you created directly from a `String` is up to you though.

Comment: is it possible to load .css file using any template loaders(like string template loader)?

Comment: Currently i have added my css strings(loaded from db) to freemarker configuration object's shared variable. Then am a accessing that variable in ftl files. But i want to know if any better way is there to do

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. But yes, you can load CSS from `TemplateLoader`-s, just like a template. Then they can be inserted into the HTML like `<#include "some.css">`, or `<#include "some.css" parse=false>` if no template features are needed.